# Color halftone effect with Core Image

Tags: ios, filter, core-image

I am trying to create color halftone effect with Core Image for iOS. Unfortunately, the effect CICMYKHalftone is not available on iOS and CIDotScreen is mono only.

Have anyone successfully created color halftone effect by chaining CIDotScreen and other filters together?

Comment: Split the RGB channels, use CIDotScreen, merge the channels.

Comment: Can you be more specified about what filters to use for chaining?

Comment: @duci9y - Yeah would be interested to hear what you mean by that specifically. Anyway you could write it up as an answer?